# Normalising layout between browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

So I've been building a layout and up until now I hadn't tested it on any non-webkit browsers.

But now that i've tested it on ie8 and firefox I've found some issues that I would like to address.

The site:

- http://thepelican.me/ablehearing/index2.html

First of all, **Internet Explorer 8.**

Regardless of any compatibility mode or turning off javascript I am still getting all of these issues.

- Elements positioned in the header are completely off.
- The text ' For effortless hearing...' and the number should be inline and floated to the right.
- The `<ul class="head">` just doesn't show at all.
- Neither does `<ul class="mainmenu">`
- A few other css styles just do not happen

**Firefox**

- I've built a layout where after scrolling through `<div id="maincontentbody">` the header element scrolls out of view and `<div id="footerblock">` scrolls into view. But in firefox it just gets stuck when you scroll to 100% of the screen height.

---

**UPDATE**
- Another way to solve the firefox issue is via jquery/js, if I could know when the user has scrolled to the end of 100% of the page and then run some kind of function which would switch scrolling from `maincontentbody` to `body` but I am pretty confused as how I can do this, I'm having trouble catching the user once they've reached 100%, innerHeight isn't giving me the correct results.

---

I am absolutely lost as to how to correct these issues and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start off with importing a [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css) to set all default browser styles to something that is the same across all browsers.